# Python Pandas : how to set 2 colums at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas

I posted something simpler because I thought it could be easy to understand, but referring to your comments, I was wrong, so I edit this question :

So here is the code. I want to do it without a loop, should it be done in pandas ?

```
import pandas as pd

myval = [0.0,1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5,6.6, 7.7, 8.8,9.9]
s1 = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
s2 = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1] 

posin = [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
posout = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
sig = ['-']

d = {'myval' : myval, 's1' : s1, 's2' : s2}

d = pd.DataFrame(d)

'''
normaly the dataframe should be with the 6 col,
but I can't make the part below working in the df.(THAT is the problem !!)
The real df is 5000+ row, and this should be done for 100+ sets of values,
so this way is not eligible. Too slow.
'''

for i in xrange(1,len(myval)) :
    if (s1[i]== 1) & (s2[i] == 1) & (posin[i-1] != 0 ) :
        posin[i]= 0
        posout[i]= posin[i-1] / myval[i]
        sig.append( 'a')
    elif (s1[i] == 0) & (s2[i] == 1) & (posin[i-1] == 0) :
        posin[i]= posout[i-1] * myval[i]
        posout[i] = 0
        sig.append( 'v')
    else :
        posin[i] =  posin[i-1]
        posout[i] = posout[i-1]
        sig.append('-')

d2 = pd.DataFrame({'posin' : posin , 'posout' : posout , 'sig' : sig })

d = d.join(d2)

#the result wanted :

print d

    myval  s1  s2  posin     posout    sig
0    0.0   0   0  10.000000  0.000000   -
1    1.1   0   0  10.000000  0.000000   -
2    2.2   1   1   0.000000  4.545455   a
3    3.3   1   0   0.000000  4.545455   -
4    4.4   0   1  20.000000  0.000000   v
5    5.5   0   0  20.000000  0.000000   -
6    6.6   1   1   0.000000  3.030303   a
7    7.7   1   0   0.000000  3.030303   -
8    8.8   0   1  26.666667  0.000000   v
9    9.9   1   1   0.000000  2.693603   a
```

Any help ?

Thanks for it !!

Comment: Is performance an issue? Otherwise just loop over the index of the frame...

Comment: Yes it is, I've done it with a loop but it's awfully sloooow...

Comment: Can you post raw input data and desired output, thanks

Comment: basically what you're asking can be done either by using 3 `loc` statements or a bunch of nested `np.where` statements but it's better you show us real input data and desired output data

Comment: I have edit the question, and change bin :-( and bout var name by  by posin and posout.

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that something like the following might work (as suggested in the comments), however (suprisingly?) this use of np.where raises a `ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape` (using a 1D to select from a 2D):

```
np.where(df.s1 & df.s2,
         pd.DataFrame({"bin": 0, "bout": df.bin.diff() / df.myval}),
         np.where(df.s1,
                  pd.DataFrame({"bin": df.bout.diff() * df.myval, "bout": 0}),
                  pd.DataFrame({"bin": df.bin.diff(), "bout": df.bout.diff()})))
```

---

As an alternative to using where, I would construct this in stages:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({"bin": 0, "bout": df.bin.diff() / df.myval})
res.update(pd.DataFrame({"bin": df.bout.diff() * df.myval,
                         "bout": 0}).loc[(df.s1 == 1) & (df.s2 == 0)])
res.update(pd.DataFrame({"bin": df.bin.diff(),
                         "bout": df.bout.diff()}).loc[(df.s1 == 0) & (df.s2 == 0)])
```

Then you can assign this to the two columns in df:

```
df[["bin", "bout"]] = res
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but after tweaking it since I've edit the question, it seems it doesn't give the result. My code in the following answer.

Comment: @BPulsart as you've found it's better to provide an example dataframe, your attempted code sample, and the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Code referring to  Andy Hayden's answer :

```
import pandas as pd

myval = [0.0,1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5,6.6, 7.7, 8.8,9.9]
s1 = [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1]
s2 = [0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1] 

posin = [10,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] 
posout = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
sig = ['-']

d = {'myval' : myval, 's1' : s1, 's2' : s2,'posin' : posin , 'posout' : posout   }

d = pd.DataFrame(d)

res = pd.DataFrame({"posin": 10, 'sig' : '-', "posout": d.posin.diff() / d.myval})

res.update(pd.DataFrame({"posin": 0,
                         'sig' : 'a',
                         "posout":d.posin.diff() / d.myval }
                         ).loc[(d.s1 == 1) & (d.s2 == 1) & (d.posin.diff() != 0)  ])

res.update(pd.DataFrame({"posin": d.posout.diff() * d.myval,
                         'sig' : 'v',
                         "posout": 0}
                         ).loc[(d.s1 == 0) & (d.s2 == 1) & (d.posin.diff()) == 0])


d[["posin", "posout", 'sig']] = res

print d

   myval  posin  posout  s1  s2 sig
0    0.0     10       0   0   0   v
1    1.1      0       0   0   0   v
2    2.2      0       0   1   1   v
3    3.3      0       0   1   0   v
4    4.4      0       0   0   1   v
5    5.5      0       0   0   0   v
6    6.6      0       0   1   1   v
7    7.7      0       0   1   0   v
8    8.8      0       0   0   1   v
9    9.9      0       0   1   1   v
```

Comment: Andy, I think the problem in this code is there is no if/elif/else, so it does all the first update and then the second, and since the result of a row depends of the previous, it doesn't work.

Comment: the elif/else is done with the loc/update, since these cases are distinct.

Comment: I don't get it... it doesn't  match the result showed in the code upside. The code on the top is good, but too slow.

Comment: originally (when you posted) there was no code, I don't quite follow the example but the **strategy** in my answer ought to work. Or is the problem this is a "rolling" style question, in which case you may have to [cythonize](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas) to get performance.

Comment: @ Andy : ok, doing it in Pandas seems not possible (at least I got no solution), so I have to speed it up with Cython. Thanks for the help.